# Javascript Events not attached after partial reload in IE7+

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, onclick

I have a js file that is loaded for all pages which contains a popup dialog function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.popup').on('click', function(e) {
        alert('Show Dialog');
    });
});
```

This is working when the page is first loaded. However when an object element is udated using:

```
$(this).html(data);
```

It seems the a.popup event is not attached anymore. This problem only occurs in IE7+. It works in chrome, firefox and opera. Anyone know what might be causing the issue and a workaround for it?

Comment: are you using an updatepanel?

Comment: what is `this`? The `a.popup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('a.popup').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('Show Dialog');
});
```

Use:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.popup', function(e) {
    alert('Show Dialog');
});
```

See also: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. **If new HTML is being injected into the
>   page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML
>   is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.**
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.
>
> In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements
>   not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their
>   potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be
>   monitored. On a data table with 1,000 rows in its tbody, this example
>   attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

> A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one
>   element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level
>   (from the clicked tr to tbody):

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `live` function for event binding

See http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: live is deprecated, .on() should be used instead.